# How to Update a table in vertica with a fixed value while joining with other table?

Tags: vertica

I have This query in Mysql:

```
UPDATE table1 AS a
JOIN table2  AS b ON a.code=b.code
AND b.rating < 3
SET a.Status = 'Delisted';
```

When using this in Vertica I am getting the error: 'Syntax error at or near "JOIN"'
Can someone help please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged two different database systems?

Answer (score 5):

Try this(without `JOIN`, Vertica is smart enough):

```
update table1 as a set status = 'delisted'
  from table2 as b
  where a.code = b.code and b.rating < 3;
```

---

For more info read [here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/Queries/SubqueriesInUPDATEAndDELETEStatements.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In Vertica the syntax is a bit different, you will have to use the **EXISTS** statement

```
UPDATE table1
   SET Status = 'Delisted'
 WHERE EXISTS (select *
          from table1 a
          JOIN table2 b ON a.code = b.code
                       AND b.rating < 3);
```

On JOINS allowed on updates.
I hope this was helpfull.

Comment: well exists did not actually work because there were multiple codes fulfilling the criteria. but i used 'Where code in (select code from)' and it is working now. Thanks